# How to delete duplicate records from Hive table?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to learn about deleting duplicate records from a Hive table.

My Hive table: 'dynpart' with columns: Id, Name, Technology

```
Id  Name  Technology
1   Abcd  Hadoop
2   Efgh  Java
3   Ijkl  MainFrames
2   Efgh  Java
```

We have options like 'Distinct' to use in a select query, but a select query just retrieves data from the table. Could anyone tell how to use a delete query to remove the duplicate rows from a Hive table.

Sure that it is not recommended or not the standard to Delete/Update records in Hive. But I want to learn how do we do it.

Comment: Is there a way to fasten the process? my dynamic-partitioned ext. hive table contains over 1 Mil records, with over 10% duplicates.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use insert overwrite statement to update data

```
insert overwrite table dynpart select distinct * from dynpart;
```

Comment: Is there any other way where we don't have to delete the entire table and delete records

Answer (score 11):

Just in case when your table has duplicate rows on few or selected columns. Suppose you have a table structure as shown down below:

```
id  Name    Technology
1   Abcd    Hadoop
2   Efgh    Java       --> Duplicate
3   Ijkl    Mainframe
2   Efgh    Python     --> Duplicate
```

Here id & Name columns having duplicate rows.
You can use analytical function to get the duplicate row as:

```
select * from
(select Id,Name,Technology,
row_Number() over (partition By Id,Name order by id desc) as row_num
from yourtable)tab
where row_num > 1;
```

This will give you output as:

```
id  Name    Technology  row_num
2   Efgh    Python           2
```

When you need to get both the duplicate rows:

```
select * from
(select Id,Name,Technology,
count(*) over (partition By Id,Name order by id desc) as duplicate_count
from yourtable)tab
where duplicate_count> 1;
```

Output as:

```
id  Name    Technology  duplicate_count
2   Efgh    Java             2
2   Efgh    Python           2
```

Comment: How to get rid of duplicate value

Comment: @JonAndrews regarding vikrant's answer, using the query within a CTE command will be a solution for removing the duplicates: e.g. with duplicates_rank as (select Id,Name,Technology,
row_Number() over (partition By Id,Name order by id desc) as row_num
from yourtable) delete from duplicates_rank where row_num<>1

Answer (score 2):

you can insert distinct records into some other table

```
create table temp as select distinct * from dynpart
```

Comment: or without new table: `insert overwrite table dynpart select distinct * from dynpart`

Comment: @fi11er, your answer is working. If you can put your comment in an answer, I will accept it.