# Is there a way to check how many rows inserted in Hive table while inserting operation?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

While doing insert operation in hive table all data inserting properly, But i need to know whether 1000 records i am going to inserting in hive table at the  time some network issue was happen so the job will failed ,Then hive job was  stopped with 500 records,so again i need to start same hive job for inserting ,for in that scenario the duplicate will occur i think so , So how can avoid this duplicate insertion and i need to get my last insert record rows in my current job could you anyone aware of that, let me know.How can archive this kind of scenario it will helpful for me .Thanks.

> [How to delete duplicate records from Hive table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280052/how-to-delete-duplicate-records-from-hive-table)

For this link will explain for a how can delete duplicate record for after insertion i don't want to do this and i don't want to store some another duplicate table also.

Comment: If you want to know the #rows inserted you need to catch the hive logs, or redirect the hive logs to a file. For deleting the records if you know time for the last 500 records insertion just delete those files from hdfs based on the time stamp of the hdfs files.

Answer (score 0):

Hive jobs would be translated to MR jobs. 
During insert operations, Hive would

1. write data to a **staging directory** (not the target directory)
2. move everything from the **staging directory** to the **target directory**.

So usually you do not need to worry about this, and there would be no duplicate data if the insert operation fails at half, because they are in the **staging directory** until the whole job succeeded.

If you want to get how many rows, just run

```
select count(*) from $table;
```

Usually hive would save metadata for DML operations, so usually this would return immediately without raising an extra MR job.

Comment: Thanks  for the Response @Harper,and one more think there is any possibility how many rows inserting while running job  in the job itself, like i need to insert 1000 record now running on 432 rows like that? like a heart beat of hive response in every rows insertion,if its there let me know.

Comment: Again, the result of the insert operation would be ALL or Nothing, so the number 432 is of no sense for you.
But if you want to monitor the job processing procedure, you could visit the Application master on yarn to get these information.